# Pig on grouping

Tags: apache-pig

I tried to count the number of occurences of each member_id.
The data look like: (member_id, item_type)

2020292 Abc

2020292 Acd

2020292 Abc

2938201 CDE

Then the output would be something like (id, count):

2020292 3

2938201 1

I tried the following:

```
data=FOREACH data GENERATE member_id, item_type;
grouping=group data by member_id;
count_elements=foreach grouping generate flatten(group) as member_id, COUNT(data) as num_elements;
```

I also tried similar codes for count_elements like 'foreach grouping generate member_id, COUNT(data) as num_elements;'
and 'foreach grouping generate flatten(group) as member_id, COUNT(data.item_type) as num_elements;' and neither one is working.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input :**

```
2020292,Abc
2020292,Acd
2020292,Abc
2938201,CDE
```

**Code :**

```
read = load 'test.data' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,item_typ:chararray);
grouped_Data = group read by id;
describe grouped_Data;
count_val = foreach grouped_Data GENERATE group as (member_id:int),COUNT(read) as (rec_cnt:int);
dump count_val;
```

**Output :**

```
(2020292,3)
(2938201,1)
```

Comment: THANKS so much!! :) Do you also know how to filter the id's by the id's from another table? For instance, another table called "id_list" has a list of id's, and we want to show the result of count_val only on id's that are in the "id_list". Can we do something like "count_val2 = filter count_val by id in id_list;"?

Comment: `join_data = JOIN count_val BY member_id, id_list_data BY member_id;` <br/> <br/> `group_joined_data = FOREACH join_data GENERATE count_val::member_id AS id, count_val::rec_cnt AS count_item_type;`

Answer (score 0):

Jenny, I added the code for your question and also for the question you asked in the above comment (@Learner's answer).

**Input Data:**

```
2020292,Abc
2020292,Acd
2020292,Abc
2938201,CDE
```

Sample data for **id_list**:

```
2020292
2020291
2020290
```

**Pig Script:**

```
data = LOAD '/pigsamples/groupdata' USING PigStorage(',') 
       AS (member_id:INT, item_type:CHARARRAY);
id_list_data = LOAD '/pigsamples/groupidlist' USING PigStorage(',') AS (member_id:INT);

group_data = GROUP data BY member_id;
count_grouped_data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE group AS member_id, COUNT(data) AS count;

join_data = JOIN count_grouped_data BY member_id, id_list_data BY member_id;

group_joined_data = FOREACH join_data GENERATE count_grouped_data::member_id 
                    AS id, count_grouped_data::count AS count_item_type;
```

**Output:**

```
(2020292,3)
```